# Identifying actual fragments in Activity OnFragmentResumed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Android project with multiple activities. All activities extend BaseActivity which has the following overridden function:

```
override fun onFragmentResumed(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {
    super.onFragmentResumed(fm, f)
    f.apply { Timber.e(f.javaClass.simpleName + " opened") }
}
```

Basically, the purpose of the function above is to log every fragment name the instant it is opened. This works fine; the only problem is that it logs some non-fragment classes as well. I've illustrated a sample response below:

> 2021-01-20 17:03:23.328 1/com.sample E/BaseApplication$AdjustLifecycleCallbacks: LoginActivity opened
>
> 2021-01-20 17:03:38.773 1/com.sample E/BaseApplication$AdjustLifecycleCallbacks: IntermediaryActivity opened
>
> 2021-01-20 17:03:38.778 1/com.sample E/BaseActivity$onCreate: NavHostFragment opened
>
> 2021-01-20 17:04:40.691 1/com.sample E/BaseActivity$onCreate: zzc opened
>
> 2021-01-20 17:04:41.288 1/com.sample E/BaseApplication$AdjustLifecycleCallbacks: ProfileActivity opened

How can I prevent `zzc` and `NavHostFragment` from showing among the logs above? I want to display only actual fragment names.

Comment: `NavHostFragment` absolutely is a fragment. What makes you think that `zzc` isn't also a fragment (perhaps from an obfuscated library like Google Play services that uses fragments internally)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I see that now. Thanks. I came up with a clean approach to solve the problem >> answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onFragmentResumed` is triggered when there's a fragment change in any Activity that extends BaseActivity. This could be as a result of any fragment change at all: *user-defined, library, etc*.

Here's a cleaner approach:

1. Create a base fragment that all user-defined fragments would extend
2. Make all the fragments extend the base fragment
3. The fragment name in `onFragmentResumed` should only be logged if the fragment is extending base fragment.

Here's how to implement step 3:

```
override fun onFragmentResumed(fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment) {
    super.onFragmentResumed(fm, f)
    if(f is BaseFragment) {
        f.apply { Timber.e(f.javaClass.simpleName + " Resumed") }
    }
}
```

This way, only the names of fragments that extend BaseFragment would be logged.